# How to create a query in NSMutableArray and print out results?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have got a NSMutableArray that is structured as follow:

```
{
    {
      AccountNumber:Test1
      Type: Electricity
    }

    {
      AccountNumber:Test2
      Type: Water
    }    

    {
      AccountNumber:Test3
      Type: Water
    }   
}
```

How to print out the account number that are in Water type?

What I have tried is as follow:

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:(id)data{ return data; }
```

But I didn't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each item in the array is a NSDictionary, and all the keys/values are NSStrings, you could do something like this:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in myArray) {
    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"Water"]) {
        NSLog(@"Account number %@", [dict objectForKey:@"AccountNumber"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out [NSPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html). It will allow to you essentially define a query and apply it to your array to filter the results. This is much faster than a iterative loop through the array to find what you are looking for. For your example, you would simply need to do the following:

```
NSString *type = @"Water";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Type == %@", type];
NSArray *results = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```